# PfSense double nat and opening ports with ISP modem

Tags: nat, pfsense

At the office we I have a router/modem from my ISP which cannot be used in bridge mode, unfortunately. So I'll have to work with double NAT.

**Setup:**

(82.xx.xx.xx "wan" - ISP modem/router - 192.168.2.254 "lan") ->  (192.168.2.254 "wan" - PfSense box - 10.0.6.1 "Lan") -> Network gear(servers).

I'm using a PfSense box for the firewall for my network. My FTP server work perfectly, but i can't get other ports to work. For example port 8080.

Here you can see the firewall log in PfSense

[image: Here you can see the firewall log in PfSense].

When I try to connect from my cell phone (4G) to it. As you can see it the source is my cell phone and the destenation is the WAN adress of the PfSense box.

The firewall rule is the same rule as the ftp rule.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What model did your provider hand out? Does it allow multiple ´NAT´ entries to coexist? Can you put your pfSense box inside a ´DMZ´ from the modems perspective?

Comment: Its a ZTE H368N. Yes, it allows multiple NAT entries to coexist. It also has the option to put the PfSense box in DMZ. But it didn't help much.